# C++ working with converting NSStringwithformat: to something else Cocos2dx

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Still very new to C++ so go easy, but I'm having a little issue here.

I'm running a for loop to add sprite frames but I'm having some trouble translating my objective-c to C++

Objective-c

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        [initalTurnAnimationFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", tilt, i]]];
}
```

C++

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

    stringstream tempString;
    tempString <<i<<".png";        
    frameStore->addObject(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(tempString.str().c_str()));
}
```

but each time i get bad access with a quote that says "reference count should greater than 0"

please help, also if i have missed basic concepts which im sure i have could you please point them out!

thanks!

Comment: "reference count should greater than 0" means you're doing something wrong with the objc, not the c++.  C++ typically doesn't use reference counting.

Comment: cocos2dx implements it's own base CCObject class that uses reference-counting system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteFrames works together with Spritesheets. Add a spritesheet with

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile(<#const char *pszPlist#>)
```

You can create a spritesheet with many tools. I use Texturepacker. An alternative should be Zwoptex.
When you create the Spritesheet with Texturepacker you get a Spritesheet and a .plist file. The above parameter is the name of the .plist file. In this .plist file are keys.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(key)
```

The method gives you a CCSpriteFrame* from a previous added Spritesheet. If you never added a Spritesheet will it throw the error you just experienced.